# Performance of IQueryable versus Dictionary

Tags: linq, performance, dictionary, subsonic3, iqueryable

I'm caching a whole bunch of static metadata in my app at startup. It's from a db and there are tons of Foreign Key relationships.  I'm looking into the best way of modelling them.
I've just started off with LINQ.

It's easy for me to declare a class

```
public class AllData {
    public static IQueryable<libm_ColPurpose> IQ_libm_ColPurpose = libm_ColPurpose.All();
    public static IQueryable<libm_ColType> IQ_libm_ColType = libm_ColType.All();
...
```

(I'm using SubSonic 3 to generate my classes, but that's beside the point).
Then I can use the IQueryable`<T`> members to get access to anything I want, for example:

```
libm_ColType ct = AllData.IQ_libm_ColType.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ColTypeStr == this.DefaultJetColTypeStr);
```

Prior to using IQueryable I was using Dictionaries to store FK relationships, so to mimic the above code I'd code the following from a preexisting  List`<libm_ColType`> list

```
Dictionary<string, libm_ColType> colTypeByColTypeStr = new Dictionary<string, libm_ColType>();
foreach (libm_ColType x in list) { rtn.Add(x.ColTypeStr, x); }
```

and then I could use

```
libm_ColType ct = colTypeByColTypeStr[this.DefaultJetColTypeStr];
```

OK, so finally we get to the question !

The Dictionary lookup by ID is extremely efficient, however the IQueryable solution is far more flexible and elegant.

I'm wondering how much of a performance hit I'm going to get using IQueryable.  I suspect I am doing a linear scan of the list each time I call it, and that's really gonna add up over repeat calls if there are a lot of records involved.
It woul be great if I could identify unique-valued columns and have a hashtable generated and cached after the first lookup, but I suspect this is not gonna be part of the offering.

This is a bit of a dealbreaker for me regarding using LINQ.

Note (I'll repeat it again) that I'm NOT pulling data from a database, it's already in memory and I'm querying it there, so I'm only interesting in looking up the in-memory IQueryable`<T`>.

Comment: Jeez, after having a look around at LINQ-to-Object Q's, I'm wondering if I actually HAVE loaded all the data from the database into IQueryable<T> or if I've just set up a huge set of individual DB retrievals about to go off when I reference them.  I AM new to LINQ ! Maybe I should stick with my typed lists !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IQueryable represents a collection in a data-store, so you probably *don't* have the collections in memory. If you explicitly want in-memory collections, then I would go back to your dictionaries. Remember, this doesn't prevent you from using LINQ queries over the data.